# SolrCloud - How to resolve "Could not find collection configName"

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to start Solr in `SolrCloud` mode. I have created a new collection from `collection1` and changed its name in file `core.properties` by setting the property `name=logmail`.

But when I start Solr, I am getting the following error

```
$ java -Dcollection.configName=logmail -DzkRun -Dnumshards=2 -DBootstrap_confdir=./solr/logmail/conf -jar start.jar
```

> 2165 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader  –
>   Updating cluster state from ZooKeeper...  2179
>   [OverseerStateUpdate-94955713964081152-127.0.1.1:8983_solr-n_0000000001]
>   INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer  – Starting to work on the main
>   queue 2197 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Looking
>   for core definitions underneath /home/rahul/Desktop/dev/solrcloud/solr
>   2203 [main] INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Found core
>   logmail in /home/rahul/Desktop/dev/solrcloud/solr/logmail/ 2204 [main]
>   INFO  org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Found core collection1 in
>   /home/rahul/Desktop/dev/solrcloud/solr/collection1/ 2204 [main] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoresLocator  – Found 2 core definitions 2207
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – publishing core=logmail state=down collection=logmail 2207
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – publishing core=collection1 state=down collection=collection1 2208
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – numShards not found on descriptor - reading it from system property
>   2208 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – numShards not found on
>   descriptor - reading it from system property 2214
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – look for our core node name 2214 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – waiting to find shard id in
>   clusterstate for logmail 2214 [zkCallback-2-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.DistributedQueue  – NodeChildrenChanged fired on
>   path /overseer/queue state SyncConnected 2215
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – Check for collection zkNode:logmail 2222
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – look for our core node name 2222 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Creating collection in
>   ZooKeeper:logmail 2222 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – waiting to find shard id in
>   clusterstate for collection1 2223 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Looking for collection
>   configName 2223 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Check for collection
>   zkNode:collection1 2224 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Creating collection in
>   ZooKeeper:collection1 2224 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Looking for collection
>   configName 2225 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Could not find collection
>   configName - pausing for 3 seconds and trying again - try: 1 2226
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – Could not find collection configName - pausing for 3 seconds and
>   trying again - try: 1 2226
>   [OverseerStateUpdate-94955713964081152-127.0.1.1:8983_solr-n_0000000001]
>   INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer  – Update state numShards=null
>   message={   "core":"logmail",   "roles":null,
>   "base_url":"http://127.0.1.1:8983/solr",
>   "node_name":"127.0.1.1:8983_solr",   "state":"down",   "shard":null,
>   "collection":"logmail",   "operation":"state"} 2226
>   [OverseerStateUpdate-94955713964081152-127.0.1.1:8983_solr-n_0000000001]
>   INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer  – node=core_node1 is already
>   registered 2227
>   [OverseerStateUpdate-94955713964081152-127.0.1.1:8983_solr-n_0000000001]
>   INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer  – shard=shard1 is already
>   registered 2255 [zkCallback-2-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader  – A cluster state change:
>   WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:NodeDataChanged
>   path:/clusterstate.json, has occurred - updating... (live nodes size:
>   1) 2268
>   [OverseerStateUpdate-94955713964081152-127.0.1.1:8983_solr-n_0000000001]
>   INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer  – Update state numShards=null
>   message={   "core":"collection1",   "roles":null,
>   "base_url":"http://127.0.1.1:8983/solr",
>   "node_name":"127.0.1.1:8983_solr",   "state":"down",   "shard":null,
>   "collection":"collection1",   "operation":"state"} 2268
>   [OverseerStateUpdate-94955713964081152-127.0.1.1:8983_solr-n_0000000001]
>   INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer  – node=core_node1 is already
>   registered 2269
>   [OverseerStateUpdate-94955713964081152-127.0.1.1:8983_solr-n_0000000001]
>   INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.Overseer  – shard=shard1 is already
>   registered 2288 [zkCallback-2-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.DistributedQueue  – NodeChildrenChanged fired on
>   path /overseer/queue state SyncConnected 2318 [zkCallback-2-thread-1]
>   INFO  org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader  – A cluster state
>   change: WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:NodeDataChanged
>   path:/clusterstate.json, has occurred - updating... (live nodes size:
>   1) 5227 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Could not find collection
>   configName - pausing for 3 seconds and trying again - try: 2 5228
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – Could not find collection configName - pausing for 3 seconds and
>   trying again - try: 2 8229 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Could not find collection
>   configName - pausing for 3 seconds and trying again - try: 3 8229
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – Could not find collection configName - pausing for 3 seconds and
>   trying again - try: 3 11232 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Could not find collection
>   configName - pausing for 3 seconds and trying again - try: 4 11232
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – Could not find collection configName - pausing for 3 seconds and
>   trying again - try: 4 14237 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] INFO 
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Could not find collection
>   configName - pausing for 3 seconds and trying again - try: 5 14237
>   [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] INFO  org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController
>   – Could not find collection configName - pausing for 3 seconds and
>   trying again - try: 5 17237 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] ERROR
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Could not find configName for
>   collection logmail 17238 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2] ERROR
>   org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController  – Could not find configName for
>   collection collection1 17240 [coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-1] ERROR
>   org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer  – Error creating core [logmail]:
>   Could not find configName for collection logmail found:null
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZooKeeperException: Could not find
>   configName for collection logmail found:null

Comment: What version of Solr are you using?

Comment: I am using Solr version 4.10.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there may be a discrepancy between what Solr has on the filesystem for collections based on your commands and what is in zookeeper.

These are hard to fix; if possible I would recommend to delete your configuration files out of zookeeper and reload them.

Answer (score -2):

You have a typo in your command. This should do the trick:

```
$ java -Dcollection.configName=logmail -DzkRun -Dnumshards=2 -Dbootstrap_confdir=./solr/logmail/conf -jar start.jar
```

Comment: Hi Fallout, could you please tell me where exactly is the typo ? I have compared the command with the command in your answer. They are identical.